# R: Is there a maximum number of columns allowed in a list

Tags: r, limit, gnu

I tried to expand a table with new values but it failed at the 100 somethings' column. So I did a test with the following code. Only the first 100 columns are added. Is this R's limit or can I bypass it somehow?

```
x <- list()
x$c1 <- NA
x$c2 <- NA
x$c3 <- NA
x$c4 <- NA
x$c5 <- NA
x$c6 <- NA
x$c7 <- NA
x$c8 <- NA
x$c9 <- NA
x$c10 <- NA
x$c11 <- NA
x$c12 <- NA
x$c13 <- NA
x$c14 <- NA
x$c15 <- NA
x$c16 <- NA
x$c17 <- NA
x$c18 <- NA
x$c19 <- NA
x$c20 <- NA
x$c21 <- NA
x$c22 <- NA
x$c23 <- NA
x$c24 <- NA
x$c25 <- NA
x$c26 <- NA
x$c27 <- NA
x$c28 <- NA
x$c29 <- NA
x$c30 <- NA
x$c31 <- NA
x$c32 <- NA
x$c33 <- NA
x$c34 <- NA
x$c35 <- NA
x$c36 <- NA
x$c37 <- NA
x$c38 <- NA
x$c39 <- NA
x$c40 <- NA
x$c41 <- NA
x$c42 <- NA
x$c43 <- NA
x$c44 <- NA
x$c45 <- NA
x$c46 <- NA
x$c47 <- NA
x$c48 <- NA
x$c49 <- NA
x$c50 <- NA
x$c51 <- NA
x$c52 <- NA
x$c53 <- NA
x$c54 <- NA
x$c55 <- NA
x$c56 <- NA
x$c57 <- NA
x$c58 <- NA
x$c59 <- NA
x$c60 <- NA
x$c61 <- NA
x$c62 <- NA
x$c63 <- NA
x$c64 <- NA
x$c65 <- NA
x$c66 <- NA
x$c67 <- NA
x$c68 <- NA
x$c69 <- NA
x$c70 <- NA
x$c71 <- NA
x$c72 <- NA
x$c73 <- NA
x$c74 <- NA
x$c75 <- NA
x$c76 <- NA
x$c77 <- NA
x$c78 <- NA
x$c79 <- NA
x$c80 <- NA
x$c81 <- NA
x$c82 <- NA
x$c83 <- NA
x$c84 <- NA
x$c85 <- NA
x$c86 <- NA
x$c87 <- NA
x$c88 <- NA
x$c89 <- NA
x$c90 <- NA
x$c91 <- NA
x$c92 <- NA
x$c93 <- NA
x$c94 <- NA
x$c95 <- NA
x$c96 <- NA
x$c97 <- NA
x$c98 <- NA
x$c99 <- NA
x$c100 <- NA
x$c101 <- NA
x$c102 <- NA
x$c103 <- NA
x$c104 <- NA
x$c105 <- NA
x$c106 <- NA
x$c107 <- NA
x$c108 <- NA
x$c109 <- NA
x$c110 <- NA
x$c111 <- NA
x$c112 <- NA
x$c113 <- NA
x$c114 <- NA
x$c115 <- NA
x$c116 <- NA
x$c117 <- NA
x$c118 <- NA
x$c119 <- NA
x$c120 <- NA
x$c121 <- NA
x$c122 <- NA
x$c123 <- NA
x$c124 <- NA
x$c125 <- NA
x$c126 <- NA
x$c127 <- NA
x$c128 <- NA
x$c129 <- NA
x$c130 <- NA
x$c131 <- NA
x$c132 <- NA
x$c133 <- NA
x$c134 <- NA
x$c135 <- NA
x$c136 <- NA
x$c137 <- NA
x$c138 <- NA
x$c139 <- NA
x$c140 <- NA
x$c141 <- NA
x$c142 <- NA
x$c143 <- NA
x$c144 <- NA
x$c145 <- NA
x$c146 <- NA
x$c147 <- NA
x$c148 <- NA
x$c149 <- NA
x$c150 <- NA
View(x)
```

Comment: The object is intact. But the spread sheet viewer `View` cuts some columns away from `as.data.frame(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limit.  Try `names(x)` and you'll see all the columns are there.  Another good function for inspecting objects is `str(x)` but this output is truncated for such a large object.  I don't use `View()` but it either has a limit (not apparent from the help page) or it's just clunky.

Comment: How would you display the table if not with View()?

Comment: The way you created it is as a `list` but it's not really that complicated / necessary.  I would convert to a data frame and then export it as a csv to view it in detail, if necessary.  `x2 <- as.data.frame(x); write.csv(x2, file = "x2.csv")`.  Data frames are actually a type of list with equal length columns.  If you really need a true list in the long run, there is no general way to view it, you'd have to look at the elements individually.